# select, postgres jsonb, cast() as alias, and where

Tags: sql, postgresql, column-alias

I'm a bit stumped getting an SQL query to work, using Postgress 9.5. Here is the table schema:

```
dbhost-> \d item

                          Table "public.item"
 Column |  Type   |                               Modifiers
--------+---------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------
 id     | integer | not null default nextval('items_id_seq'::regclass)
 emails | jsonb   | not null
Indexes:
    "items_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
    "items_emails_key" UNIQUE CONSTRAINT, btree (emails)
```

In that jsonb field, "emails", all entries will encode a list of strings. Something like `["alpha@example.com", "beta@example.com"]`. And I want to find all rows whose FIRST element in the list starts with a particular string prefix.

I thought this query would work:

```
select
  cast(emails::json->0 as text) as entry
  from item
  where entry like 'some_prefix%'
  limit 5;
```

But I get this error:

```
ERROR:  column "entry" does not exist
LINE 4:   where entry like 'some_prefix%'
```

This must be a basic syntax error on my part. Can anyone see what I missed?

Comment: You can't use the alias in the where condition, you have to repeat cast(emails::json->0 as text)

Comment: That's the insight I was missing. Thanks @FrankHeikens